# sync items movement between 2 listboxs

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

[image: this is my listboxs]

I try this but didn't work for me

`private void listBoxControl2_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxControl5.SelectedIndex = listBoxControl2.SelectedIndex;
    }`

the question is sync movement of the selector on both listboxs for example if listbox1 was selected item 2 the other listbox should be on item 2 and if i move scroll on one of them the other should act same

Comment: Don't use two ListBoxes!  Use a **ListView** with two columns instead...

Comment: I need the one with links be invisible  I just put on a question to people understand what's im asking

Comment: Will the links always be invisible?

Comment: yes always @Idle_Mind

Comment: Then you don't need the second ListBox.  Create a **Class** to hold the FileName and Links in separate fields; then override the `ToString()` method of that Class so that it returns only the FileName.  Create instances of that class and add them to the ListBox (instead of Strings as you're doing now).  The FileName will be displayed because of the ToString() override.  You can cast the current selected item to your Class type and retrieve the Link value (or any other values you add to that class!).

Comment: im asking so much but would help little im kinda bad of handling class @Idle_Mind

Comment: Get the question re-opened and I can post an answer.

Comment: i can't @Idle_Mind

Comment: Yes, you can.  I have voted to re-open your question.  Edit your question above so that others will see you've changed the focus of your question and they wil also vote to re-open it.  Get enough votes and others (including myself) will be able to add new answers to it.

Comment: I edit it @Idle_Mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
var itemIndex = listBoxControl2.SelectedIndex;
ListBoxControl5.SelectedItem = 
    ListBoxControl2.Items.IndexOf(itemIndex);
```

Comment: the "GetItemAt" is not define i don't know what's wrong

Comment: @elmissouri please see edit

Comment: I fix it now give me no error but isn't working